# How to pick API end-points for multiple relationships between the same entities?

Tags: api, rest, relationship, endpoint

I'm having trouble picking end points for two similar queries. So my db entities are User and Course, they have 2 relationships between them. The first relationship is M to M: A user is learning many courses and a course can be learned by many users. The second relationship is 1 to M: a course can be edited by one user and a user can edit many courses. Now for the API endpoints, I need to get:

1. all the courses a user is learning
2. all the courses a user can edit

I can only see `/users/me/courses` as a potential endpoint, but how do I distinguish between the relationships that I want the query based on in the end-point?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
/users/me/editable-courses
/users/me/joined-courses
```